# Replace data of a column with data of another column same table names, same column names different databases names

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, sql-insert

Updating an older version of prestashop to a newer version. Having trouble creating a query to migrate column data from source db to destination db (same column and table names, different db names).

In other words, I need to replace the data of destination column with data of source column. This is the query I have so far:

```
INSERT INTO `destination_db`.`destination_table` 
Select * FROM `source_db`.`source_table` 
on duplicate key UPDATE `destination_db`.`destination_table`.`destination_colum`=`source_db`.`source_table`.`source_column`;
```

After running the query, this is the result: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)

Any help to fix the query is truly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you just run the SELECT statement from the source_db 'Select * FROM `source_db`.`source_table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this as it seems to me that you may have just made a small mistake with you're syntax

You forgot to put the UPDATE {tableName} SET {column} = {sourceColumn}.

```
INSERT INTO `destination_db`.`destination_table` (`destination_db`.`destination_table`.'destination_column1',`destination_db`.`destination_table`.'destination_column2',`destination_db`.`destination_table`.'destination_column3')
SELECT 
       `source_db`.`source_table`.'source_column1',
       `source_db`.`source_table`.'source_column2',
       `source_db`.`source_table`.'source_column3'      
FROM 
        `source_db`.`source_table` 
ON 
     DUPLICATE KEY 
            UPDATE `destination_db`.`destination_table`.`destination_column1`=`source_db`.`source_table`.`source_column1`;
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Robbie! Ran the query and this is the result: "MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows)" any thoughts?

Comment: What does the main source Select * FROM source_db.source_table Statement return?

Comment: You know what...after clearing the cache, it looks to have worked!